# Display highest value in array in C

Tags: c, arrays

When I run this, ageProgMax comes out as 29 instead of what I want, 60. I did this for the smallest number of cafes that analysts drink and it worked but somehow this one doesn't.

```
int main()
{
    char poste[] ={'P', 'P', 'O', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'P'};
    int nbCafe[] ={5, 1, 3, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2};
    int age[] ={25, 19, 27, 22, 49, 24, 60, 29};
    int nbPers = sizeof(age) / sizeof(int);
    int i;
    int ageProgMax = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nbPers; i++)
        if (poste[i] =='P' || age[i] > ageProgMax)
        {
      ageProgMax = age[i];
        }
    printf ("Max age of programmers : %d\n", ageProgMax);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Step through the code with your debugger.  Debuggers are amazing.

Comment: What is the purpose of `poste`? And why does `'P'` overrule the age comparison?

Comment: poste are the jobs. its a table showing jobs (programmers P, analysts A and operators O) next column is number of coffees that each drink and the last one is the age of each person. 

I have to display the highest age of the programmers, so I tried to use a double condition as if when the job is programmer and the age is higher than the integer ageProgMax.. is that not the correct way to do so?

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55078258/edit) your question to include the significance of this array and how it should affect the output. Yes, it is the correct way to do this, you just used the wrong boolean operator, see @Mazhar's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `||` in your condition. Look at the condition you have set i.e. `if (poste[i] =='P' || (age[i] > ageProgMax))`. It says to store new value to `ageProgMax` if either of `(age[i] > ageProgMax)` or `poste[i] =='P'` becomes true. So for the last entry i.e. `29` even though `(age[i] > ageProgMax)` is false, the `poste[i] =='P'` is true and causes the overwrite of the `ageProgMax`'s `60` with that of `29`.

You can correct your program like this.

```
int main()
{
    char poste[] ={'P', 'P', 'O', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'P'};
    int nbCafe[] ={5, 1, 3, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2};
    int age[]    ={25, 19, 27, 22, 49, 24, 60, 29};
    int nbPers = sizeof(age) / sizeof(int);
    int i;
    int ageProgMax = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nbPers; i++)
    {
        if (poste[i] =='P' &&  (age[i] > ageProgMax))
        {
            ageProgMax = age[i];
        }
    }

    printf ("Max age of programmers : %d\n", ageProgMax);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define MAX(a,b)    ((*(a)) > (*(b)) ? (a) : (b))

int *largest(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    int *result = NULL;
    if(arr && size)
    {
        if(size == 1)
        {
            retult = *arr;
        }
        else
        {
            result = MAX(arr, arr + 1)
            arr += 2;
            size -= 2;
            while(size--)
            {
                result = MAX(result, arr);
                arr++;
            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Returns NULL on error or pointer to the largest int.

Comment: @Michail of course - SO should invest in the code editor

Comment: Answers are supposed to address questions not just give alternative approach.